# How to parse JSON string to get original data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am new to this.

I am making use of JSON string.

My jquery looks like

```
      var data1 = {};                            
      data1.code = $("#ddlList option:selected").text();   //Taking dropdown list value


           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
                data: JSON.stringify(data1),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var data = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var data = $.parseJSON(data);

                    $.each(data, function (i) {
                        $("#Table").append("<tr><td>"  "</td></tr>");
                    });
```

My `GetData` WebMethod is returning a JSON string containing data of Data Table

```
       {["\"id"\:"\"10001"\"\"name"\:"\"ABC"\]}         //JSON string
```

contains following

```
          System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

`return serializer.Serialize(rows);` is returning above JSON string but I want to convert this JSON string  to table on server side in success function

I checked my solution, I am getting string value in success function.
I tried as above jquery function but I want JSON string values in table(how to deserialize it so to get table )

(    I have modified `$("#Table").append("<tr><td>"  "</td></tr>");`   )

Comment: `var data = JSON.stringify(data); var data = $.parseJSON(data);` ? `data` is already an object

Comment: Yes. data here is `{["\"id"\:"\"10001"\"\"name"\:"\"ABC"\]}` I don't know how to parse. Because I want id and name as columns and 10001 and ABC as tr data

Comment: jQuery parses the JSON for you such that the `data` argument in the success function is already an object. You can access the id for the first item in the array with `data[0].id`; the name will be `data[0].name`.

Comment: [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Have you verified what value you are getting in variable data? and check what you are getting value in data.d

Answer (score 0):

parse you data using `JSON.parse` and then in your `$.each` use two parameters i, v where `i` is the index and `v` is the object and access your value as `v.id` and `v.name` . To specify which column represents what just specify the headers of the table as  `$('#Table').append("<th><td>ID</td><td>NAME</td></th>");`

```js
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
                data: JSON.stringify(data1),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(data);
                    $('#Table').append("<th><td>ID</td><td>NAME</td></th>");
                    $.each(data.d, function (i, v) {
                        var str = "<tr><td>" + v.id +"</td><td>" + v.name + "</td></tr>";
                        $("#Table").append(str);
                    });

          });
```

Comment: Thanx for the solution. I've already tried it. but getting values as `undefined undefined`

Comment: @A.Dubey can you print the properly formatted data you get in success function and then post in yout code. Your original version doesn't seen to be correct

Comment: Do you mean I write proper JSON string ??

Comment: Yes something like {'values': [{'id': '3', 'name': 'abc'}, {'id': '5', 'name': 'cfd'}]}

Comment: {"d":"[{\"id\":10001,\"name\":\"ABC\}]"}

Comment: Now after parsing the response you can loop over it using $.each(data.d, function(){})